# How to detect UIButton background image change?

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, uibutton

I work on iOS 8 with objective C on Xcode.
I need to create two viewControllers.
First: button with background image that is changed to some random image, and go to second controller. 
Second: Present button image name

Both view Controllers are created but, i need to know about :

1.How to detect that the image on the button  is changed on the First view ,if i now on Second viewController?

2.How to pass the file name to the second viewController ?

Comment: How are your two controllers connected? Did you ctrl drag from the button on storyboard? Or are you instantiating the second view controller another way?

Comment: Are you using segues? or storyboard ID to move onto second view controller?

Comment: "1.How to detect that the image on the button is changed on the First view ,if i now on Second viewController?"    Please explain this. Do you want to get notified at second view controller when the button image is changed on first view controller?

Answer (score 1):

you can get back the image with :

[self.button currentImage]

(also works with currentBackgroundImage/Title/TileColor... rtfm ;))

To pass data to your second view controller many options exists, you can use "prepareForSegue" and set you next view button/NString whatever :)

Good Luck ;)